# docker-compose: Installing newer PostgreSQL and removing old data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a postgresql database running in docker (using docker-compose) for app development. I tried to update (or actually recreate) the database to a newer postgresql version by updating "docker-compose.yml" file, but I receive an error when running "docker-compose up":

- "The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 11, which is not compatible with this version 14.0"

How do I clear the data directory or completely recreate the image? This is a development database, so the data can just be removed without needing to migrate it. I have tried running "docker-compose down --volume", but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Recreating the volume should work. You should be able to do this with core docker commands if compose isn't working for you